# Java Area constructor hangs for certain curves

Tags: java, geometry, awt, infinite-loop, freeze

The `Area(Shape)` constructor hangs for certain strange `Shape` arguments, as demonstrated below. Every single commented line hangs, and no non-commented line hangs. I see this behavior with Oracle Java 8 and 10.

```
import java.awt.geom.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // new Area(new CubicCurve2D.Double(0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0));
    new Area(new CubicCurve2D.Double(0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    new Area(new CubicCurve2D.Double(0, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0));
    new Area(new CubicCurve2D.Double(0, Double.MAX_VALUE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0));
    new Area(new CubicCurve2D.Double(0, Double.MIN_VALUE, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0));
    new Area(new CubicCurve2D.Double(0, Double.NaN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0));

    // new Area(new CubicCurve2D.Double(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));
    new Area(new CubicCurve2D.Double(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));

    // new Area(new QuadCurve2D.Double(0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0, 0, 1, 0));
    new Area(new QuadCurve2D.Double(0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    new Area(new QuadCurve2D.Double(0, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, 0, 0, 1, 0));
    new Area(new QuadCurve2D.Double(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1));

    // new Area(new QuadCurve2D.Double(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));
    new Area(new QuadCurve2D.Double(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));

    // new Area(new QuadCurve2D.Double(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));
    new Area(new QuadCurve2D.Double(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY));

    // new Area(new QuadCurve2D.Float(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY));
    new Area(new QuadCurve2D.Float(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY));

    Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
    path.moveTo(1, 0);
    path.quadTo(0, 0, 0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    // new Area(path);

    new Area(new Line2D.Double(0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0, 0));
    new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0, 0));
}
```

What in the world is going on here? Are there other `Shape`s that cause the `Area` constructor to hang?

Primary question: ignoring `CubicCurve2D`, `QuadCurve2D`, and `Path2D` objects with `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` for any coordinate (I'll deal with those as an edge case), **can I safely assume that the `Area` constructor will never hang?**

Note that I can't apply standard debugging techniques to this problem because I don't have access to Oracle's `Area` source code, so all I can do is treat it as a black box. I'm wondering if there are other known inputs that cause this black box to hang.

---

*Please don't say this is a pointless question because no sane person would write this code... I have an application that is running randomly-generated Java code and this is actually a problem. Please also don't suggest I run the code in a separate process and kill it after some timeout, because that approach is too slow for my needs.*

Comment: for such complexity why don't you use builder pattern?, just suggestion

Comment: @emotionlessbananas How is that relevant? Did you read the question?

Comment: You should draw an approximation of your curves, to gain insight into why the Area object hangs; I suspect that maybe the algorithm for closing the curve is struggling with some points configurations.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Can you be more precise? I don't have access to Oracle's source code for the Area constructor, so all I can do is speculate. Notice that in my examples, switching the `x` and `y` coordinates can cause different behavior, as can swapping a `0` for a `1`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're passing `Integer.POSITIVE_INFINITY` as the argument, Java API ends up generating `NaN`s (Not a number) in the calculation which leads to an `infinite loop`

All of the above commented methods have following Stacktrace after the thread is suspended

```
Thread [main] (Suspended)   
    Order1(Curve).compareTo(Curve, double[]) line: 935  
    Order1.compareTo(Curve, double[]) line: 221 
    Edge.compareTo(Edge, double[]) line: 90 
    AreaOp$NZWindOp(AreaOp).pruneEdges(Vector) line: 278    
    AreaOp$NZWindOp(AreaOp).calculate(Vector, Vector) line: 159 
    Area.pathToCurves(PathIterator) line: 195   
    Area.<init>(Shape) line: 126    
    AreaTest.main(String[]) line: 8
```

There's an infinite loop running in `Order1(Curve).compareTo(Curve, double[]) line: 935` from line `935 to line 945` according to debugger, since we don't have source code and this class was not compiled with debug information we can't rely on the line numbers exactly. However we can look close those lines in `OpenJDK` source.

**Note:** `Order1(Curve).compareTo` method is from `Order1`'s superclass `Curve`

Following is the code location where `NaN` is generated

```
sun.awt.geom.Curve.compareTo

Oracle JDK decompile code (Enhanced class decompiler)

    //Renamed variables with INFINITY. prefix to signify that their value is INTEGER.POSITIVE_INFINITE
    label101:
    for (arg30 = arg2 + arg24; arg30 <= INFINITY.arg4; arg30 += INFINITY.arg26) {
        if (!this.fairlyClose(this.XforY(arg30), arg0.XforY(arg30))) {
            NaN.arg30 -= INFINITY.arg26;

OpenJDK source code

    while (y <= y1) {
        if (fairlyClose(this.XforY(y), that.XforY(y))) {
            if ((bump *= 2) > maxbump) {
                bump = maxbump;
            }
        } else {
            NaN.y -= INFINITY.bump;
```

Oracle line `NaN.arg30 -= INFINITY.arg26;` or OpenJDK line `y -= INFINITY.bump;` would generate `NaN` on second iteration as `INFINITY - INFINITY` is `NaN`.

Lets look at the following quickly

1. Any logical operation involving `NaN` always results into `false`
2. Any arithmetic operation always results into `NaN`

Now following is the infinite loop

```
sun.awt.geom.Curve.compareTo

//Renamed variables with INFINITY. and NaN. prefix to signify their value as NaN or INFINITY

Oracle JDK decompile code (Enhanced class decompiler)

    while (true) {
        INFINITY.arg26 /= 2.0D;
        NaN.arg32 = NaN.arg30 + INFINITY.arg26;

        //Loop termination condition is always false, due to NaN in logical operation
        if (NaN.arg32 <= NaN.arg30) {
            break label101;
        }

        if (this.fairlyClose(this.XforY(NaN.arg32), arg0.XforY(NaN.arg32))) {
            NaN.arg30 = NaN.arg32;
        }
    }

OpenJDK source code

    while (true) {
        bump /= 2;
        double NaN.newy = NaN.y + NaN.bump;

        //Loop termination condition is always false, due to NaN in logical operation
        if (NaN.newy <= NaN.y) {
            break;
        }
        if (fairlyClose(this.XforY(newy), that.XforY(newy))) {
            y = newy;
        }
    }
```

Loop termination condition ends up introducing `NaN` in the condition which always results in false, because of that loop never breaks.

OpenJDK code reference http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/sun/awt/geom/Curve.java#936

**Note:** I have tested the same code on `openjdk version "1.8.0_151"` and it hangs there too.

Following are my suggestions to handle it

1. Timeout is the best strategy. You should also detect resource utilization like RAM, disk and network usage. If you're running code from unverified sources it should definitely be run under a separate process, not only that it should be run into a separate environment altogether like in a `Docker` container.
   Timeout/Resource utilization measurement is used by most online programming competitions like `CodeChef`. You can try running an infinite loop on https://ideone.com and see that it ends fairly quickly, most likely because of timeout. Even a container is not foolproof, and unverified code could exploit your container's vulnerability and get access to the host. Checkout this video https://youtu.be/rfjmeakbeH8?t=2035, I have marked the current time in the video where container isolation strategies are shown.
2. There's no other strategy :) it's [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) from computer science which is [NP Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness), meaning there's probably no polynomial time solution to this problem yet.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have an answer to my primary question, which is: "are there other inputs, aside from `CubicCurve2D`, `QuadCurve2D`, and `Path2D` objects with infinite coordinates, that cause `Area` to hang"? This isn't exactly the halting problem because we aren't solving this for arbitrary programs. We have one fixed program (i.e., Oracle's `Area` constructor), and with the decompiled code (which I don't have the tools to produce), it could be possible to prove or disprove the existence of other inputs that cause a hang.

Comment: I wasn't aware of even this case before you brought this up. I got curious and started debugging it. For decompilation I used `Spring Tool Suite 3.8.2.RELEASE` with plugin `Enhanced Class Decompiler 3.0.0` https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enhanced-class-decompiler. Both of these are free so you can use them for your testing. Also source code for OpenJDK is open. Regarding the halting problem, yes it requires arbitrary program and arbitrary input. I'm not sure about the given program and arbitrary input, it's probably `undecidability problem`, don't know about any others that cause it.